# Hibernate One-to-One and Many-to-One relationship strange behaviour after saving entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use Spring Boot with Spring Data, and for saving entities i use CrudRepository. I have 2 entities: Org and OrgDef. The idea is to store multiple definitons for one Org. Org is immutable part, and OrgDef is mutable. This is how it looks in code:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "org", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "code" }, name = "uk_org_code"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "definition_id"}, 
    name = "uk_org_definitionId")})
public class Org {

@Id
@Column(
    name = "id",
    updatable = false,
    nullable = false
)
protected UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

@Column(updatable = false)
protected String code;

@JoinColumn(nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_org_definition_orgDef"))
@OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
protected OrgDef definition;

}



@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "org_def")
public class OrgDef extends UuidIdEntity {

@Id
@Column(
    name = "id",
    updatable = false,
    nullable = false
)
protected UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();    

@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_orgDef_orgId_org"), updatable = false)
@ManyToOne
protected Org org;

@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_orgDef_parentId_org"))
@ManyToOne
protected Org parent;
}
```

Also i want to note that Org has One-to-One relation to OrgDef, and OrgDef has Many-To-One relation to Org. Also OrgDef has "parent" field, that also has Many-to-One relation. When i save records of this class i have this in my tables:

**Org** table:

[image]

**OrgDef** table:
[image]

You can see that in table **OrgDef** field **org_id** is null, but **parent_id** is not null. But while saving i specify **Org** object for both **org** and **parent** fields in **OrgDef** object. May be problem in mapping? Can someone help? Because **parent** field of **OrgDef** is saved fine, but **org** field in **OrgDef** not saving! My expectations is that both **org_id** and **parent_id** will be not null

Comment: Please share the code you wrote for saving the data

Comment: Shouldn't your Org to OrgDef relationship be a OneToMany relationship. I am not quite sure how you can even have multiple OrgDefs for one Org. I mean what OrgDef is connected to the Org of the many you have. Is there a specific reason why you use foreignKey and not just mappedBy and name? Also why not cascade delete? What good is an OrgDef for if you don't have an Org?

Comment: @kaba713 it is special structure) It means that i srote a history of modifications, this structure is very useful. Yes i know that this is not correctly mapped, but this mapping solve my business logic

Comment: In that case your entity should still have a OneToMany relationship and your business logic should only give away the newest OrgDef if that's what your Org is supposed to do. You should not rely soly on the mapping for a correct history of modification. Other than that Hibernate does have a way of historising elements for you it's called Envers: http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/.

Comment: @kaba713 yes, Org entity has One-to-One relation to OrgDef, and in any modification i set newest version of OrgDef to Org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, i use this annotation on org field of OrgDef class:

```
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_orgDef_orgId_org"), updatable = false)
```

I specify that this field is not updatable, so hibernate can't insert value to this field. I removed `updatable = false` from this annotation and now all works fine!

Comment: This works fine, but I would suggest to use the column name in the JoinColumn annotation so that it would be clear in the code(for other developers).

Comment: I didn't understand all these relations. However, it still looks strange to me. One-to-one means that the two entities share the same primary key value. This doesn't seem to be the case here. Be careful with foreign keys. It might look correct when only using a low number of test records.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger the reason of this mapping is to store definition of entity in separate entity, and we can store  a history of modifications. For example i have Person and PersonDef. PersonDef will have a name, surname, phone, address and etc. And Person will have only unique Id and reference to PersonDef (one-to-one), but if i want to rename my person and update name field, i will create new record in PersonDef table. With this operations i can store a history of midifications, and Person class will have last version of PersonDef. This mapping solve my business logic.

Comment: Ok, I know this pattern. I implemented exactly the same. This is definitively not a one-to-one relation, since many Defs point to the same Person. Since one-to-one is a primary-key relation, it cannot be changed. When it is supposed to be the "currently valid def" or "latest def" in sense of the latest in history, so it will change whenever you add a new def.